# Solved exercises source for nonlinear control

Tags: reference-request, control-theory, nonlinear-system

Soon I will be taking an exam on nonlinear control theory. I have exhausted the lecture material and I am looking for a compilation of solved exercises to practice as much as possible. Could someone recommend such a document?

The curriculum includes gain scheduling, feedback linearazation, sliding mode control and optimal control.